# Using struct as key for dictionary and weird stuff is happening

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, struct, iequatable

Heres my struct...

```
internal struct Coord : IEquatable<Coord>
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Coord(int x,int y) : this(){ X = x;
        Y = y;}

    //Overloaded operator functuions below
    //So I can easily multiply Coords by other Coords and ints and also add Coords together
    public static Coord operator *(Coord left, int right)
    {
        return new Coord(left.X * right, left.Y * right);
    }

    public static Coord operator *(Coord left, Coord right)
    {
        return new Coord(left.X * right.X, left.Y * right.Y);
    }

    public static Coord operator +(Coord left, Coord right)
    {
        return new Coord(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y);
    }

    public static Coord operator -(Coord left, Coord right)
    {
        return new Coord(left.X - right.X, left.Y - right.Y);
    }


    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + X;
        hash = hash * 31 + Y;
        return hash;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return other is Coord ? Equals((Coord)other) : false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Coord other)
    {
        return X == other.X &&
               Y == other.Y;
    }
}
```

I'm using these as keys for a dictionary, but I dont think they are equating to each other properly..
The values in the dictionary are objects with a bool field.
I have a  while loop that does stuff to them and changes the bool to true until they are all true.. It gets stuck in an infinite loop as they never get changed to true.. Whats weird is that I dont get any out of range errors or anything like that and when I debug the bit where the bool is changed it seems to work fine but when I look at the dictionary in debug all the bools are still false

(note: i was using a Tuple as the key but I made this struct so I could multiply and add them easily )

I just want to check with you that...

```
  _myDictionary = new Dictionary<Coord, RogueRoom>();
  _myDictionary[new Coord(4,5)] = new RogueRoom();
  _myDictionary[new Coord(4,5)].Connected = true
```

Those two times I access the dictionary I am accessing the same value object?

EDIT: Here is the value struct in the dictionary (I replaced "thing" above)

```
internal struct RogueRoom
{
    public Room RoomField;
    public bool Connected;
    public Rectangle Realpos;
    public Color[] RogueRoomColors;
    public Coord Gridpos;
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete example of it failing to equate properly.

Comment: Struct looks fine to me. Error must be elsewhere? Are you using == to compare them anywhere? Because you haven't overloaded operator ==()

Comment: No, just using them as keys and then using == on the bool in the value object

Comment: Is `Thing` a struct or a class?

Comment: If you do: var thing = new Thing(); _myDictionary[new Coord(4,5)] = thing; What does object.ReferenceEquals(thing, _myDictionary[new Coord(4,5)]) return?

Comment: @Guye If `Thing` is a `struct`, this code will not do what you expect it to.

Comment: http://ideone.com/aR6PqL <--- This is an example of it working properly.

Comment: @Pete Based on that, the only logical remaining explanation is that `Thing` is a `struct`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Not quite, I can think of ways of making this not work with `Thing` as a class, but they're a lot less likely, for example `Thingbool` might be a property that just doesn't save the value at all.

Comment: @Servy True, but `Thing` being a `struct` is the most likely way to make it fail without realising :-P

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Actually, the code wouldn't compile if `Thing` was a struct...

Comment: @ Servy. thing is a struct!

Comment: @GuyeIncognito Then this code won't compile.  You should get the error: "Cannot modify the return value of [...] because it is not a variable".  The dictionary indexer is returning a *copy* of the `Thing` value, so you're modifying that copy.  This is such a common error and is virtually always a mistake, so it is actually a compiler error.

Comment: @Servy Very true, forgot about that. Got too hung up on the getter returning a copy of the struct and not a reference.

Comment: Ok, thanks all!! I must go look up why you cant have struct keys and values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what `Thing` is. If `Thing` is a `struct`: no; the value is copied when it is fetched - although the compiler will usually stop you assigning properties against a `struct` that is about to be thrown away. If it is a `class`, then it *should* be the same object instance; your equals/hash-code look reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `_myDictionary[new Coord(4,5)].Connected = true;` should not compile, since methods and properties whose return type is a struct (e.g. `_myDictionary[new Coord(4,5)]`) return read-only copies of those structure types and you are trying to write to such a read-only structure.

For brevity, I'm going to pretend your dictionary was a `Dictionary<int, RogueRoom>`; the fact that `Coordinate` is a user-defined structure doesn't matter here.

If you say `var temp = _myDictionary[5];` that statement will generate a writable *copy* of the `RogueRoom` instance.  If you say `temp.Connected=true;` that will modify *that copy* but leave the copy in the dictionary unchanged.  If you wish to update the one stored in the dictionary, you would have to write it back yourself: `_myDictionary[5] = temp;`.

If you were to change `RogueRoom` to a mutable class, then you could say `_myDictionary[5].Connected = true;` to modify the `Connected` property of the object associated with 5.  For better or for worse, however, it would also modify the `Connected` property associated with any other reference that exists to that same object.  For example, if one were to say `_MyDictionary[2] = _MyDictionary[5];`, then the statement `_myDictionary[5].Connected = true;` would set the connected property of the object associated with 2 (since the object associated with 2 is the same object as is associated with 5).

Some people dislike mutable structures, and would suggest that you should design your type so that code would have to say something like:

```
var temp = _myDictionary[5];
_myDictionary[5] = new RogueRoom(temp.RoomField, true, temp.RealPos,
   temp.RogueRoomColors, temp.GridPos);
```

instead of just updating the `Connected` property of `temp` and writing it back.  I find the latter style to be needlessly ugly and obscure, but some people prefer it.

As for the question of whether the thing should be a class, that depends upon whether you want each storage location of type `RogueRoom` to hold hold five independent pieces of information which are independent from those in any other storage location of that type, or whether you want to allow multiple storage locations of that type to refer to the same instance.  There are definite usage cases for both scenarios; you need to determine which is right for you.